# Using INNER JOIN resulting table in another INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm not really sure that the title actually corresponds, maybe my approach is wrong.

I have the following database structure:

```
TABLE producers
    id

TABLE data
    id
    date 
    value 
    producer_id OneToMany
```

First thing first, for each producer, I want to get the latest `date` of registered `data` that there is. The code below does exactly this:

```sql
SELECT producers.id AS producer_id, max.date AS max_date
FROM producers
INNER JOIN data ON producers.id = data.producer_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT producer_id, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM data
    GROUP BY producer_id
) AS max USING (producer_id, date)
```

And the resulting table is:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|   producer_id   |             max_date           |
----------------------------------------------------
|       5         |  2022-01-01 01:45:00.000 +0000 |
|       7         |  2022-01-01 01:45:00.000 +0000 |
|       14        |  2022-01-01 01:45:00.000 +0000 |
|       15        |  2022-01-01 01:45:00.000 +0000 |
|       17        |  2022-01-01 01:45:00.000 +0000 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

The next thing that I need is to `SUM` all the `data` records per producer **WITH** `date` bigger than the `max_date` we got for each producer after the `INNER JOIN` from the previous query. The `SUM()` will be performed on column `value`.

Hopefully that was clear, if not, let me know. I've tried doing another `INNER JOIN` and use table `max` in the `WHERE` clause but I got an error that told me that the table was there, but it wasn't possible to be used in that part of the query.

Maybe another `INNER JOIN` isn't the solution. Here I'm limited by my knowledge of SQL and I don't really know about which keywords to read more in-depth to understand what's the best approach and how to do it. So, an info to redirect me on the best path would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to specify on which column the `SUM()` will be executed on.

EDIT 2: Just realized that what I'm asking here, the result will always be an empty table because there won't ever be a record whose `date` will be bigger. When I wrote the simplified version of my database, forgot to add a table/join, that's why. But in the end imo the approach/solution will still be the same, just applied on a different table. Sorry for that again.

Comment: what col are you going to `sum()`?

Comment: @etch_45 Oh sorry forgot to mention, `value`

Comment: Your first query can be simple: https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/44dd5bc0ba728fdd12a58b77c08c7fc4/

Comment: Good point, tho in my real scenario I do other `INNER JOIN`s beside this one, so that's why I cannot do it this way. But I'll remember, thanks.

Comment: Please: Make the best question post you can, if you have an answer post that to. Don't unask your question & don't edit an answer into it. But don't edit in a way that invalidates posted answers. [ask] [answer] [Help] [meta] [meta.se] For code questions give a [mre]. Please don't include greetings, apologies, etc. Please don't insert the word "EDIT" etc or otherwise say you edited, just edit to the best presentation possible.

Comment: @philipxy Ok I'll keep that in mind. I just added the EDIT comments because overtime I saw that this practice is used by people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query in the question can be greatly simplified using `distinct on` and `order by`:

```sql
select distinct on (p.id)
       p.id, d.date
from producers p
join data d on p.id = d.producer_id
order by p.id, d.date desc;
```

As for "SUM all the data records per producer WITH date bigger than the max_date" - well, none exists with date bigger than the latest one. Here is a query to do so (even the result will be empty)

```sql
select producer_id, sum(value)
from data d inner join -- the query above follows
(
  select distinct on (p.id)
         p.id producer_id, d.date
  from producers p
  join data d on p.id = d.producer_id
  order by p.id, d.date desc
) t using (producer_id)
where d.date > t.date
group by producer_id;
```

Comment: By the way the first query can be simpler then mine as @SlavaRozhnev suggests in his comment.